# Security issues in reading passwords from keyboard using batch file

Tags: security

We have a requirement where we need to trigger a batch file to read password without an echo from a perl script which will be used to create users on windows platform. My question is there any way someone can assess the memory and read the password after the batch file has been run.

Answer (score 0):

If by memory you mean the PowerShell history, they probably could. Have your script include a

```
Clear-History
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849733.aspx before finishing the script. If you mean the device's physical memory, that depends on a series of factors, and any exploit allowing someone to arbitrarily read memory (and the ability to know which memory they need to read) has already gotten an enormous amount of access to your system.

Comment: Hi, yes, I agree with, if someone can access the physical memory then he can do a lot of damage any how....

Comment: Hi, yes, I agree with you, if someone can access the physical memory then he can do a lot of damage anyhow..... Coming back to the script, the  script is invoked from a perl script and hence I believe I don't need to worry about power-shell history, or am I missing something...,